# WPF C# Get Cell value from autogenerated Data Grid and Data Table

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created simple mechanism for data table xaml would looks simply:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentsFlagValuesView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

And MVVM code behind is based on data tables, and as well fairly simple:

```
private void GenerateDataView()
{
    CurrentsFlagValuesView = new DataTable();
    CurrentsFlagValuesView.Columns.Add("Bits");

    var bitLength = 0;

    foreach (CurrentsFlagAnalysis flag in CurrentsFlagValues)
    {
        CurrentsFlagValuesView.Columns.Add(flag.DailyCurrentsTimestampInterval.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        bitLength = flag.CurrentFlagsLength;
    }

    for (var bit = 0; bit < bitLength; bit++)
    {
        List<CurrentFlagEventEnum> flags = CurrentsFlagValues
            .Select(value => value.CurrentFlags.ElementAt(bit))
            .Select(value => value ? (CurrentFlagEventEnum)bit + 1 : CurrentFlagEventEnum.None)
            .ToList();

        var dataRowValues = new List<object> { bit };
        dataRowValues.AddRange(flags.Cast<object>());

        CurrentsFlagValuesView.Rows.Add(dataRowValues.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But I came upon a problem, or two I want to get data of the cell when I click the cell, like Column title, and value of the cell. I managed to do this without MVVM like:

```
void EditingDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell Cell = EditingDataGrid.GetCurrentDataGridCell();
    var Position = Cell.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

    TextBlock text = (TextBlock)Cell.Content;

    MessageBox.Show("Value=" + text.Text, "Position" );
}

public static DataGridCell GetCurrentDataGridCell(this DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = dataGrid.CurrentCell;
    if (cellInfo.IsValid == false)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return cellContent.Parent as DataGridCell;
}
```

But now I want to remodel that to that pattern, but I do not know how. Any Ideas how to bind command to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `CurrentCell` property of the `DataGrid` to a `DataGridCellInfo` (not `DataGridCell`) source property provided that you set the `Mode` of the `Binding` two `TwoWay`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentsFlagValuesView}" 
          CurrentCell="{Binding CurrentCell, Mode=TwoWay}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Then the source property of the view model will be set whenever you select a cell in the view and you could simply move your current logic to the view model:

```
private DataGridCellInfo _currentCell;
public DataGridCellInfo CurrentCell
{
    get { return _currentCell; }
    set { _currentCell = value; OnCurrentCellChanged(); }
}

void OnCurrentCellChanged()
{
    DataGridCell Cell = GetCurrentDataGridCell(_currentCell);
    var Position = Cell.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

    TextBlock text = (TextBlock)Cell.Content;
    MessageBox.Show("Value=" + text.Text, "Position");
}

public static DataGridCell GetCurrentDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    if (cellInfo == null || cellInfo.IsValid == false)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return cellContent.Parent as DataGridCell;
}
```

You could also wrap this functionality in a behaviour that sets the source property of the view model to the actuall cell value:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF
https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/01/30/wpf-using-behaviours-to-bind-to-readonly-properties-in-mvvm/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bind the current cell property in the view model and you will have the current cell with you all the time:

```
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
      SelectionUnit="Cell" 
      CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" 
      CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo}"            
      SelectionMode="Single">
```

In the view model:

```
private DataGridCell cellInfo;
public DataGridCell CellInfo
{
    get { return cellInfo; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns the clicked on row in the grid, starting from 0

```
int currentRowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(dtGrid.CurrentItem);
```

Get value of currentRowIndex for column 0, or a specific cell value

```
object cellContent = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dtGrid.Items[currentRowIndex]);
string valueOfColumn0currentRowIndex = (cellContent as TextBlock)?.Text;
```